# How to remove view based on a change in another view? Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, event-handling

I am trying to remove a view based on a change in another view so I can render a new view when the change has occurred. I currently have a container view, which renders a view called search, once the search button is clicked on I want to remove the view and add another view. The rendering happens in a container view (renders the view, with the model and adds the template). However, I do not know how to pass or allow the container view to listen for changes in the search view... the reason I built a container view is because I am trying to not change the route, the parameters can change from /search to /page and show the results but I am not sure how to go about doing this, even if the container view is removed and the router is controlling this, how do I allow the router to hear for changes?

I am up to listening either directions using the router or using a container view, just need to know how to listen for a change event.

Here is the code for the router:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    //'views/page',
    //'views/search',
    'views/container'

], function($, _, Backbone, Container) { //Page, Search
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend ({
        routes: {
            'page/:id': 'showPage',
            's': 'showView' ///:page
        }
    });

    var initialize = function () {
        var app_router
        app_router = new AppRouter;
         // Extend the View class to include a navigation method goTo
        Backbone.View.prototype.goTo = function (loc) {
            app_router.navigate(loc, true);
        };

        console.log('router file hit');
        app_router.on('route:showPage', function (id) {

            var page = new Page();
            page.render(id);
        });

        app_router.on('route:showView', function () {
            console.log('search file hit');
            var container = new Container();
            container.render();

        });

        Backbone.history.start();

    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Here is the code for the container view:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/search',
  'views/search',
  'text!templates/search.html',
  'views/page',
  'text!templates/page.html'
  //'collections/songs',
  //'views/song',


], function($, _, Backbone, SearchM, SearchV, SearchT, PageV, PageT){ //Song, Songs, SongV, 

  var Container = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#Sirius"),

    initialize: function () {

    },

     render: function () { 
      console.log('container rendered')
      //create new instance of the model
      var searchM = new SearchM();
      var search = new SearchV({model: searchM}); //
      this.$el.html( SearchT );
      search.render();
      //search.listenTo(this.model, 'change:display', this.displayChanged);        
    }

      });
    return Container;
});
```

Here is the code for the search view:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/search',
  'text!templates/search.html',

], function($, _, Backbone, SearchM, SearchT){ 

  var Search = Backbone.View.extend({
    //model: SearchM,
    el: $("#Sirius"),

    events: {
      'submit #searchMusic': 'search'
    },
    initialize: function () {
         this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:display', this.displayChanged);
    },
    displayChanged: function () {
       console.log('display changed');
    },
    search: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var that = this;
      //post instance to the server with the following input fields
      that.model.save({
        channel: $('#channel').val(),
        week: $('#week').val(),
        year: $('#year').val(),
        filter: $('#filter').val()
      },{success: that.storeMusic(that) });

      // on success store music on client-side localStorage
    },
    storeMusic: function (that, response, options) {
        console.log('store');
        //create new instance of the localStorage with the key name
        that.model.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("music");
        var that = this;
        that.clearLocalStorage(that);

        that.saveToLocalStorage(response, that);
      },
      clearLocalStorage: function  (that) {
        console.log('clear');

          //removes the items of the localStorage
          that.model.localStorage._clear();

          //pops out the first key in the records
          that.model.localStorage.records.shift();

        },
        saveToLocalStorage: function  (response, that) {
          console.log('save');
          console.log(that);
          that.model.save({music: response}, {success: that.nextPage(that)});
        },


        nextPage: function  (that) {
          console.log('entered next page');
          that.model.set('display', true);

        }

  });
    return Search;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a kind of mediator pattern to be able to communicate between different parts of my application, but avoid coupling them too tightly.

```
var myApp = {}; // namespace for views, models, utilities etc.
_.extend( myApp, Backbone.Events );
```

To communicate between Container and Search. Relevant parts below:

```
var Container = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo( myApp, 'changeOccured', function(){ /* do something */ });
  }
});


var Search = Backbone.View.extend({
  displayChanged: function () {
    myApp.trigger('changeOccured');
  }
});
```

The upside of this approach is that you can `listenTo` / `trigger` the `changeOccured` event in other views / models / collections without messing with `Search` View code in the future.

Comment: What is the downside? Also, I am going to eventually have another view that I am rendering and then pages in that view... so would this method become an issue?

Comment: What error do you get? You need to have underscore.js included before calling `_.extend`.

Comment: I realized I was not putting it after define, thanks this actually helped me a bit